# code not doing stuff when running normally, but does it when in debug mode, step by step

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to change the size and font of a merged cell, I've tried treating it as a range and as the first cell of the merged group. When i run the code it doesn't changes the font type nor the size, nor changes it to bold. It will change the alignment, and the wrap, but nothing about the font.

```
'treating it as range

 With Sheets("5x5").Range(Cells(filaeti + 2, columnaeti).Address, Cells(filaeti + 7, columnaeti + 4).Address)
    .WrapText = True
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Font.FontStyle = "Arial Narrow"
    .Font.Bold = True
End With


*******

'treating it as the first cell of the merged group
 With Sheets("5x5").Cells(filaeti + 2, columnaeti)
    .WrapText = True
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Font.FontStyle = "Arial Narrow"
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
```

Comment: `"Arial Narrow"` is a font `Name`, not a `FontStyle`, right? The second example works for me, changing `FontStyle` to `Name`.

Comment: `Sheets("5x5").Range(Cells(...` will fail if `Sheets("5x5")` is not active.  And you don't need those `.Address`'s